# LaTeX Symbols do not work any more

Tags: symbols

my problem should be fairly simple but I am a LaTeX Noob... :)
Using WinEdt 10 under Windows 7, compiling with PDFTeXify (standard).

If I use basic symbol commands like `\pi` or `\leftrightarrow`, no matter whether in floating text or math environment, the file does not compile any more. Otherwise, it does.

Error-Message I get:

```
! Missing $ inserted.

inserted text (in <> brackets)

$
1.87 ...r = i - \pi

?

! Emergency stop.
```

What is going on here? I am puzzled... :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! A minimal (non-)working example would help to help.

Comment: they are math mode symbols and, as the error message says you have not entred math mode with `$` as in `$\pi$` or `\begin{equation} \pi \end[equation}` etc

Comment: Thank you very much @DavidCarlisle, problem solved ;)
I knew it must've been that easy...

Comment: PS: aweseome support here, will definitely come back when writing my masters thesis lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline math requires dollars as in `$r = 1 - \pi$`, or you can use for instance `equation` as one of many other math environments. Beware that math symbols, such as `\pi` and `\leftrightarrow` *must* be put in a math environment. Your error message is LateX' reaction to facing math symbols outside a math environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
This is $r = 1 - \pi$ in an inline math environment

This is %
%
\begin{equation}
  r = 1 - \pi
\end{equation}%
%
in an equation environement
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, you can also use `\(` and `\)` for inline math.

Comment: @hooy: Yes, it's robust now since the last major LaTeX kernel update about one year ago